# Jquery - Iterate through all checked radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which is similar like the one below:

```
<form id="myForm">
      Question 1:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Yes"> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="No"> No
      <br>
      Question 2:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Yes"> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="No"> No
      <br>
      Question 3:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Yes"> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="No"> No
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want to get all the selected radio button values from all the questions using jQuery and if all values is equal to "yes", it will alert success else it will alert fail.

This is the jQuery I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myForm input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
   });
});
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: is this a demo mate?what is the problem?

Comment: first you have radio buttons not checkboxes

Comment: @Radu i didnt even notice that :)

Comment: The code in your question of the running loop on all radio type button saves my life. I am looking for this quite for two days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if you ever get no with radio checked then result is fail else success.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/tejecolaha/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
result = "success";
$("#myForm input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
  if(this.value == "No" && this.checked == true)
  {
     result = "fail";
     return false;
  }
});
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var val=1;
       $("#myForm input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
            if($(this).val()=="No")
             {
              val=2;
             }
       });

      if(val==1)
      {
        alert("Success !!");
      }
      else{
        alert("Fail ");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var no_found=false;
   $("#myForm").submit(function(){
      $(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       if(value == "No")
           no_found=true;
      });
      if(no_found==false){
       alert("Success");
      } 
      else{
       alert("Fail");
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var total = 0;
    $('#myForm input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Yes')
        total++;
    });
    if (total == 3)
      alert("Success");
    else
      alert("Fail");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  Question 1:
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Yes" checked>Yes
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="No">No
  <br>Question 2:
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="No" checked>No
  <br>Question 3:
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="No" checked>No
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var check = "Yes";
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
     if(value == "No")
      check = "No";
    });
    alert(check)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as well:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGeLMx

```
$('#myForm input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();  

  var result = true;  
  $('input[type="radio"]').each( function() {

    var radio = $(this)[0];    
    if ( radio.value === 'Yes' && radio.checked === false )
      result = false;

  });

  if ( result ) {
    alert( 'Success!' );
  } else {
    alert( 'Fail!' );
  }

});
```

Iterated all the radio buttons and if a single check on 'No' or none is selected at all it will fail, otherwise, it would mean all 'Yes' are checked - success.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
            var iCountTotal;
            var iCountCkedYes;
            iCountTotal = $('input[type="radio"]').length/2;
            iCountCkedYes = $('input[type="radio"][value="Yes"]:checked').length;
            if (iCountTotal != iCountCkedYes) {
                alert('fail')
            }
            else {
                alert('success')

            }
        });


    });


</script>



<body>

    <form id="myForm">
      Question 1:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Yes" checked="checked"> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="No"> No
      <br>
      Question 2:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Yes"> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="No" checked="checked"> No
      <br>
      Question 3:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="Yes"> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="No" checked="checked"> No
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```