# Get radio button value by classname

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a looping of the radio button which can select depend on the score, and then I have a hidden textbox that getting the code.
My problem is, I want to get the score of my Key Result

For example:
Work Management, my code for that is WM, and I want to get the score of that KRA.
All of KRA must get all the scores by radio class name. I want to do it in javascript.

```
var cname = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < deserialized.Table.Count; i++) { cname++; var name="score" + i; <tr>
  <td>
    <h5>@deserialized.Table[i].KRA_DESCRIPTION </h5><input type="hidden" name="KRA_CODE" id="KRA_CODE" value="@deserialized.Table[i].KRA_CODE" />
  </td>
  @for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) { <td><input type="radio" class="Score" name="@name" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="Score" name="@name" value="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="Score" name="@name" value="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="Score" name="@name" value="4" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="Score" name="@name" value="5" /></td>
    }
    </tr>
    }
    }
```

here is my sample result of how it is displayed.
[image]

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Basically you need to get which radio has been selected for each row and then send it through the hidden input?

Comment: Is this an answer to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290353/jquery-iterate-through-all-checked-radio-buttons

Comment: @EnricoTenca, that i want to send in the hidden input for me to send it via form ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this plain JS to take checked radio button value from your list. then set that value into your hidden text field. Hope it will solve your issue

```
function getKraValue() {

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('Score');
  var rate_value;
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      if(x[i].checked){
          rate_value = x[i].value;
      }
  }
 //now set your hidden field value
   document.getElementById('KRA_CODE').value = rate_value;
}
```

Comment: is working though, but only one hidden textbox is changing, my textbox is looping. so when it click the particular KRA, the textbox of it will change depends what radio it clicks.

Comment: @codeSeven in that case, you can put dynamic id for hidden checkbox ID. and pass that id value into getKraValue() function via onClick().  

as you are looping, your iterator variable i  has dynamic value every time it iterates. append that one with your input field id and pass that i into the param of getKraValue(i). Finally use that i to append with getElementById('KRA_CODE' + i ).value. 

Hope it make sense. let me know